# Export SQL Server database with everything related to it such as logins

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, ssms

How can I export a SQL Server database with everything related to it such as Logins/Users to use/import on another server? I think `Generate Scripts...` might be a good idea but what options should be set to `TRUE` to backup everything? or is there any other options to achieve this ?

Comment: Logins are **server-related** - they don't apply to a single database .... everything else is contained in a database backup

Comment: Thank you, Do you mean `Tasks/Backup` will do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **database backup** contains everything that's defined in that database - all db objects (tables, views, stored procedures etc.), database roles, users, permissions - everything that truly belongs to the database.

Things like logins, SQL Agent jobs etc. however are **server-scoped**, defined on the **server-level** and thus aren't contained in database backups

Comment: Good answer, but I suspect that the real question behind is the how to fix the 'Orphaned Users' problem.

Comment: @Steve: well, the database **users** are transported with the backup - but they need to be "connected" to the server-level logins at the place where the backup is restored. Don't know of any easy / automagic way to do this right now ...